Can a knight capture all 16 pawns in 16 consecutive moves?
Beginner puzzle (suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving).

To solve this problem you need not be a chess player.
You need only know the way a knight moves on the chessboard: two squares in one direction (up, down, left or right) and one square at right angles to the first direction.  A knight captures a piece if it moves to the square occupied by that piece.
The diagram below shows the positions of 16 pawns on a board.

Can a knight capture all 16 pawns in 16 consecutive moves?
Clarifications:
You can choose the knight’s initial position.
You can ignore the fact that in a legal chess game, a single knight couldn’t capture 16 pawns.

Attribution:  The Moscow Puzzles by BORIS A. KORDEMSKY.

Am I right to assume, that the pawns don't move like in a normal chess game?

@Féileacán The pawns don’t move at all.  The knight moves 16 times in a row.  This is not a normal chess game.

Oh my god, the Moscow Puzzles! I have such good memories of that book from being a kindergartener or so (although the references to kopeks and that sort of thing always went over my head due to my lack of knowledge of any details of my grandparents' lives in Russia). I remember in particular puzzles about smearing pencils with paint, fastening and unfastening chains, and something about lead blanks (?) that produced a geometric series-y thing.

It is literally impossible to fail this puzzle: rot13(Fgneg sebz nal cnja naq znxr pncghevat zbirf hagvy lbh eha bhg, nyfb onpxjneq vs arprffnel.  Gur erfhyg jvyy or n cngu lbh pna gnxr, juvpu lbh pna ragre ng rvgure raqcbvag ba lbhe svefg zbir.)

For starters,

 The sixteen pawns lie in two blocks of eight, which can individually be captured in loops (red): 
 Connect the loops with any of the four blue moves, and disconnect one of the red loop edges that connects to one end of the blue connection. Reconnect the free end to an unoccupied initial square, and you've got yourself a solution!


To build on the earlier answer...

 We've shown the Knight can capture each group of eight pawns in sequence, and that the three squares nearest the middle of the board in each group allow jumping to the other group. These are circled in red in the image below.


 Hence, to be able to get to the second group, the Knight must start the captures of the first group from a square that allows the last capture in to be made on a circled square. Since the sequence of captures loops, the possible first-captured pawns are all the pawns that are a knight's step away from the circled ones. This happens to be every non-circled pawn.


 Then, the Knight's starting square before the captures must be such that it can reach a non-circled pawn from it. These are framed in blue in the image below.


 


I think you missed 2 squares in the centre

@htmlcoderexe, hah, I was so sure I would miss some, fixed.

A6 and H3 will, additionally, also work as starting positions. I think you have all others marked correctly. Nice solution image!

@Brain404, right, I messed them up when redrawing :facepalm: sorry

This explains every step of the way perfectly, and ends by clearly demonstrating that almost half of all the squares are suitable for starting, and once you start by taking a pawn that isn't one of the inner 6, you can't really fail to mop up one side, then cross over and repeat the process on the other side. A brilliant alternative to the other answer, which to me is just a confusing mish-mash of intersecting lines!

Partial answer only:

 Based on an answer by AxiomaticSystem:

 Part of their diagram shows a possible sequence of consecutive knight moves (marked by red lines):



 An alternate way of showing these knight moves is shown below:




I think that several years ago I found a similar puzzle in an old Martin Gardner's book (could be the Italian edition of "Mathematics, Magic and Mystery", but I am not sure).

 The smart initial passage was to acknowledge that, when moving the knight, any cell of an 8cells square is connected to 2 others cells only, so basically they can be logically re-arranged in simple circular path. Returning to this puzzle, we can draw these circles for each of the 2 8-cells  squares separately


 b2 -> c4 -> d2 -> b3 -> d4 -> c3 -> b4 -> d3 ( -> b2 ...)


 e5 -> f7 -> g5 -> e6 -> g7 -> f5 -> e7 -> g6 ( -> e5 ...)


 Finally the solutions are the oaths that starts from a cell of the first circle that, after 7 moves, lead us to a cell from where it is possible to jump on any cell of the second square (from which we can visit all the other cells of the second square) in other words from c4, d4 or d3  we can "land" on e6, e5 or f5


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!
